# How to access camera using getUserMedia from WKWebView IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, webrtc, wkwebview, getusermedia

I have been looking for an answer for this question over the past 3 weeks and no hope till now!

I know that Apple have enabled Webrtc and hence getusermedia on **Safari IOS 11**. But when trying to use getusermedia in any inapp-browser (ex. Facebook browser, twitter browser) which are built using **WKWebview** i get

> getusermedia object not found

Any help in that is highly appreciated, also if anyone know when Apple will fix such problem or what work around could be implemented to get it working?

**Update**

- as per IOS 11.3 Beta 2 released on Feb 6th, problem still exist!

N.b. I am looking for a javascript solution not a native objective C / swift solution

Comment: WKWebview have not yet implemented getUserMedia.